# Phoenix Channels detect disconnection

Tags: websocket, channel, phoenix-framework

I'm making a Phoenix application that listens to events from some general broadcaster and it sends them to all connected WebSocket client's through Channels.

Whenever WebSocket connects it subscribes to the Broadcaster

```
Kernel.send(:subscribe, self())
```

But when the socket gets closed it's not being removed from subscribers list.
Is there a way to detect disconnection of a channel member? Or can I detect if the socket I'm pushing to is already closed?

Cheers

Comment: Check `Process.monitor/1` and how process monitoring works. Also, you want to look at GenServer and the like. We rarely use things like `send/2`.